Utilization of Hertz potentials in calculations
Electrodynamics textbooks, like Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics, introduce the Hertz potentials $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_m$ and $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_e$(see Chapter 20 of the fore-mentioned book).
While they seem like powerful tools, I've found few examples of utilizing these potentials beyond the typical dipole case. Even Zangwill introduces them without applying them to an actual problem.
Are there any books/ other sources where I could find problems utilizing these? I'm looking mostly for the full Maxwell equation solutions.

Check out Panofsky-Phillips; this is how/where I learned about Hertz potentials. They are standard in antenna and radiation problems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz_vector

Have you looked at Stratton's Electromagnetic Theory textbook? Chapter VI is devoted to cylindrical waves in which he makes use of these.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
